# Remote debugging of an application in another city

Tags: java, android

Good day, I need to debug the application on a device in another city. How can I do that? Are there any Android debugging apps?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

[Genymotionis](https://www.genymotion.com/) is great, since BlueStack App Player now forces you to install some apps to continue using free version. I tried Genymotion and quite happy with speed for App development, haven't tried gaming yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Location Lat and Long in either code or emulator if using android studio. for remote debugging several apps are there on Google Play, for that you have to once connected with usb and then run some command in cmd depends on app(adb tcpip {Port No.}). you will need adb file for remote debugging though.

Answer (score -1):

this tool might come in handy, it is an android app that can expose the ADB over network:
[Remote ADB Shell](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-2-2-remote-adb-shell.2373265/)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.